# Generating combinations where the data source [10] is larger than the required combination length [5]

Tags: c#, loops, for-loop, combinations

I need to be able to generate all possible combinations of 10 integers, from a predefined int[], then return these possible combinations as a List. Each combination must be of **length 5**.

Example:

```
{1, 2, 3, 4, 5},
{2, 3, 4, 5, 6},
{3, 4, 5, 6, 7}, etc.
```

I have the following so far:

```
int[] cardFaces = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10 };
List<int[]> combos = new List<int[]>();

// For every value in the cardFaces array, get the value and the index.

foreach (var item in cardFaces.Select((value, i) => new { i, value }))
  {
    int value = item.value;
    int index = item.i;    
    int value1 = 0;
    int value2 = 0;
    int value3 = 0;
    int value4 = 0;
    int value5 = 0;

    // Need some nested loop code here, which will create combinations
    // from the cardFaces[] with a length of 5.

    int[] combo = {value1, value2, value3, value4, value5};

    combos.Add(combo);

  }
```

It should not contain any repetitions. I'm pretty new to this so I'm struggling to work out how to tackle the loop to get the combinations I need.

Comment: I think [Producing combinations, part one](https://ericlippert.com/2014/10/13/producing-combinations-part-one/) may help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a more generic implementation.  It takes a list of items to select from and the number of items to select (`k`).  In your case, `k = 5`.

It works like this: initialize `k` 'pointers' pointing to the first `k` elements of the source list.  This is the first combination.  Visually we have:

```
source:  [ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10 ]
pointers:  ^  ^  ^  ^  ^
```

To get the next combination, increment the last of the pointers:

```
source:  [ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10 ]
pointers:  ^  ^  ^  ^     ^
```

If that pointer is now one past the end of the list, then we go to the previous pointer and increment it and move the last pointer to one after it.  So let's say our current combination is the following:

```
source:  [ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10 ]
pointers:  ^  ^  ^  ^                  ^
```

If we increment that last pointer, it'll be past the end.  So instead we look at the next pointer from the end and increment it and put our last pointer one after it:

```
source:  [ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10 ]
pointers:  ^  ^  ^     ^  ^
```

Then we go back to incrementing the last pointer as usual:

```
source:  [ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10 ]
pointers:  ^  ^  ^     ^     ^

source:  [ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10 ]
pointers:  ^  ^  ^     ^        ^
```

And so on.  Each time your last pointer gets to the end, you move the next to last pointer.  Once it gets to the end (actually one before it), you move the *next* one back.  Basically once your last pointer gets to the end, you move back through the list of pointers trying to move each one forward until you find one that you can move forward.  Once you find one, you set all pointers to the sequence after it.  For example:

```
source:  [ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10 ]
pointers:  ^                 ^  ^  ^   ^
```

We'd loop back through our pointers noticing that we can't move any of them except for the first.  So we move that one to the next spot and then just reset all the others to be right after it:

```
source:  [ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10 ]
pointers:     ^  ^  ^  ^  ^
```

If the first pointer is less than k elements from the end, we're at the last combination and we can stop.

In code, that looks like this:

```
public static IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> GetOrderedPermutations<T>( IList<T> source, int k )
{
    if( k == 0 ) yield return Enumerable.Empty<T>();
    if( k == source.Count ) yield return source;
    if( k > source.Count ) yield break;
    var pointers = Enumerable.Range( 0, k ).ToArray();

    while( pointers[0] <= source.Count - k )
    {
        yield return pointers.Select( p => source[p] );

        pointers[k - 1]++;

        int i = k - 2;
        while( pointers[k - 1] >= source.Count && i >= 0 )
        {
            pointers[i]++;

            for( int j = i + 1; j < k; ++j )
            {
                pointers[j] = pointers[j - 1] + 1;
            }

            --i;
        }
    }
}
```